# Problem 9 chapter 5 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a continuous real function on $\mathbb{R}^1$, of which it is known that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\neq 0$ and that $f'(x)\to 3$ as $x\to 0$. Does it follow that $f'(0)$ exists?

**My proof:** Considering $(a,b)=(-\infty,0)$ we'll apply theorem 5.13 (L'Hospital's rule) we get that $$\lim_{t\to 0-}\dfrac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=\lim_{t\to 0-}f'(t)=3.$$

Also considering $(a,b)=(0,+\infty)$ we again apply theorem 5.13 and get that $$\lim_{t\to 0+}\dfrac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=\lim_{t\to 0+}f'(t)=3.$$
Hence $f'(0)=3.$ So answer is postive.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes.  I just perused the exact statement of L'Hospital's Rule (wanted to make sure my memory of all the hypotheses was correct), and it looks like your proof is valid.

Comment: Are you asking for verification of every proof you do in the Rudin book?

Comment: @MasterOfBinary, Of course no. Some of them I am solving myself and I am sure that they are right but sometimes there are problems in which solution I am doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. If you like, you can also use mean value theorem:

Let $t>0$, then there is $s_t \in (0,t)$ so that

$$\frac{f(t) -f(0)}{t-0} = f'(s_t).$$

As $s_t \to 0$ as $t\to 0$, we have

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(t) -f(0)}{t-0} = \lim_{t\to 0^+} f'(s_t) = 3.$$

Similar for the left limit.

Comment: Dear John Ma, nice solution!