# Exercise 5.9 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $f$ be a continuous real function on $\mathbb{R}^1$, of which it is known that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\neq 0$ and that $f'(x)\to 3$ as $x\to 0$. Does it follow that $f'(0)$ exists?

**Proof:** Considering $(a,b)=(-\infty,0)$ we'll apply theorem 5.13 (L'Hospital's rule) we get that $$\lim_{t\to 0-}\dfrac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=\lim_{t\to 0-}f'(t)=3.$$

Also considering $(a,b)=(0,+\infty)$ we again apply theorem 5.13 and get that $$\lim_{t\to 0+}\dfrac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=\lim_{t\to 0+}f'(t)=3.$$
Hence $f'(0)=3.$

L’Hospital rule applied on function $h(t)= f(t)-f(0)$ and $g(t)=t$ for $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, since $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ converge to $0$ as t tends to $0$.

The above proof is posted by ZFC. link to the original post: [Problem 9 chapter 5 from PMA Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1483636/861687)

**My Question:** isn’t the information $f^\prime (0+)$ and $f^\prime (0-)$ are equal to 3, already given in the hypothesis of lemma? Let me be more explicit, in definition 4.25 there is a following claim, $\lim_{x\to 0}f^\prime(x)=3$ exist $\iff f^\prime (0+)=f^\prime(0-)=3$. Let assume for a moment $f^\prime(0+)=f ^\prime(0-)=3$ how do we known $f^\prime (0+)=f^\prime(0-)=f^\prime(0)=3$? We may have $f^\prime (0+)=f^\prime(0-) \neq f^\prime(0)$.

**Caveat:** We can’t simply apply theorem 4.25 and corollary of theorem 5.12, because $f^\prime$ is defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $. So, all the things I said above, becomes less(maybe $0$) credible.

**Warning:** My question generally contains error and/or misunderstanding of concept. If you find something wrong then mention it on comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points here.  First, the limit you're asked to confirm is the *definition* of $f'(0)$.  Second, you can use L'Hopital's Rule (as long as you're careful to use it on each one-sided limit) because you are given that $f$ is differentiable on each one-sided neighborhood of $0$.  So because the limit that defines the derivative is equal (whether approaching from the left or the right) to the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0$, you have proven that the derivative exists at $x=0$.

Comment: Have you learned the definition of derivative?  It's:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}.$$

Apply this definition with $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was waiting for. Punish for my stupidity. I knew I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you please delete your answer so I can delete my post? Because my post is complete garbage.

Comment: @user264745 There's nothing wrong with your post.  There was something you weren't seeing, you provided context and asked for help.  At least in my opinion, that's how this site should be used.  And you may not be the only one with that particular blind spot.